# Why isn't my alternate layout override showing up for the menu item?

Tags: overrides

[image: Menu Layout Options]
I have created an override for com_content for the **category list**.

It is stored in `/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_content/category`

It is saved as a new name, copying the Joomla! override structure that I copied after clicking into my template in the back end and then clicking "create override" on the override I wanted.  This showed me the naming convention.

I can see the override if I go into Articles > Category in the backend and I can select the new override.

So I have 3 files.

1. `default-filedownloads.php`
2. `default_articles-filedownloads.php`
3. `default_children-filedownloads.php`

The files have not changed from the core files at the moment.

At some point I could go into Menu > Main Menu > My Category List Menu Item

Then I choose options, and I could see my menu override there.

I can't see it any more and I can't understand why it disappeared.

I have also created a `default-filedownload.xml` file as I'm aware that can help.  My override can be seen if I put these 4 files into /components`/com_content/views/category/tmpl/` then I can create a new menu item.

I don't want a new menu item

**How can I make something appear in a menu item, under options, where it allows me to choose a layout.**

Comment: As a note to others, because I don't have time to write the correct answer if I know it.  `_articles` and `_children` should be at the end, my code is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the documentation for category layouts that may be causing some of your issues.

> As with component layouts, category layouts only will show if (1) they
>   are specified for the category in the global or category parameters
>   and (2) there is no menu item specifically for this category (for
>   example, List Contacts in a Category, List News feeds in a Category,
>   List Web links in a Category, Category List, Category Blog).
>
> If there is a menu item set up for this specific category, that layout
>   will be used instead of the alternative category layout.

I also read in the documentation that adding an .xml file of the same name will make it a Menu Item and it seems not a category override. See the section on Alternative menu Items.

There is also a mention in bold that underscores should not be used in the name of the first file, but I wonder if the hyphen you have is causing issues for you.

> the file must not be named the same as the core file and must not
>   include underscores in the name. Additionally, there should not be an
>   XML file of the same name in this folder. (We'll discuss XML files
>   below under Menu Item Alternative Layouts.)

I found the above in this page, https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: Honestly I suspected the hyphen too.  But I created overrides using the Joomla! create overrides function and it had dates with hyphens in it.  So they definitely are not the problem.  However, for sanity, I have also removed the hyphens.  It didn't change things.  I've read that documentation thoroughly.  I really am starting to think the option to select an alternate layout within that menu is a mistake.

Comment: At some point `default-filedownload.php` could just be named `filedownload.php` as it's not technically an override any more but it's own entity.  I'm 99% sure that I saw the override working though!  Perhaps I should only include some of the files?  I think when it was working some files were named with a hyphen and some without.